# How do I include parameters in a bash alias?

Tags: alias, mkdir, bash

Trying to create:

```
alias mcd="mkdir $1; cd $1"
```

Getting:

```
$ mcd foo
usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory ...
-bash: foo: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This one was asked and answered first!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An alias can only substitute the first word of a command with some arbitrary text. It can not use parameters.

You can instead use a shell function:

```
mcd()
{
  test -e "$1" || mkdir "$1"
  cd "$1"
}
```

Comment: Could have been a shell script too? Named as a file mcd with no extension? How is a function different or better?

Comment: It wouldn't work as a shell script, because the script would run in a subshell.  In order for the cd to have the intended effect, it has to run in the caller's shell, not a subshell.

Comment: how is this function supposed to be called?

Comment: ah, fine, found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter?lq=1

Comment: this function is supposed to be called just like any other command, be it implemented by a function, a builtin or external command.  you just need to make sure the function is defined in your shell, which can be done by putting it in your shell startup files.