# Bash programming, insert arguments into bash aliases

Tags: shell, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell Script: How to pass command line arguments to an UNIX alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias)

How do I insert arguments into a bash alias?

for example,
whenever I create a new directory & I `cd` into it most of the time but for that I have to run two commands.

```
$ mkdir directory
$ cd directory
```

so, I was wondering if it is possible to create a new directory & switch to it in singly commands. tried to add the following alias in my .bashrc file:

```
alias mkdir="mkdir $@ && cd $@"
```

so, I could call it normally `mkdir directory` & it would create & then switch to that directory. But no dice, it didn't work!

Any pointers on how can I insert arguments into an alias?

Comment: [There is no way to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821495/how-do-i-include-parameters-in-a-bash-alias).

Comment: Looks like this has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider defining it as a function.

```
function mkdir2 {
  mkdir $@
  cd $@
}
```

You won't be able to alias it to mkdir in this way, but it'll do as you expect.

Comment: You can name the function mkdir, but you cannot call it recursively:  mkdir() { command mkdir $1; cd $1; }

Comment: slight improvement - quoted arguments, don't try to cd if the mkdir failed: 

`function mkdir { command mkdir "$@" && cd "$@"; }`