# variable inside awk/sed in alias

Tags: bash, sed, awk, alias

I'd like to write an alias that would print particular line from all files in a folder, i.e.:
`$ print_line 20` - would print 20th line from all files in a folder.

I spent hour with various constructions in .bashrc (some examples below), with lot of different escaping, but so far nothing worked. Thanks for any help.

```
alias a="for f in create*; do sed -n '\$1{p;q}' $f; done"
```

```
alias b="for f in create*; do awk 'NR==\$1{print $0}' $f; done"
```

```
function l { r=$(echo \'"$1"{p;q}\'); sed -n "$r" *; }
```

Comment: Why? `awk 'FNR==20' *` would do it just as succinctly as `print_line 20 *`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that'd do too. I'm not too familiar with awk and shell too, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
printline() { for f in create*; do sed -n "$1{p;q}" $f; done ;}
```

Answer (score 0):

bash aliases, unlike those in csh, do not allow parameters; see [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter) and [Passing argument to alias in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060880/passing-argument-to-alias-in-bash), and [How to pass command line arguments to a shell alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-unix-alias) and [How do I include parameters in a bash alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821495/how-do-i-include-parameters-in-a-bash-alias)

So you need a function. If you have the GNU sed with the `-s` switch, the following will work:

```
   printline() { sed -ns "$1 p" create*;}
```

Otherwise, slightly modifying sat's nice answer, use a for-loop:

```
   printline() { for f in create*; do sed -n "$1 p" "$f"; done;}
```

Note the space after the `{` is necessary. The use of double-quotes in `"$f"` guards against filenames with bad characters, such as spaces or stars.